# spring requestmapping http error 406 on file extension

Tags: java, ajax, json, http-headers, spring-boot

I have created this REST mapping so that it can accept filenames at the end of the URI ...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/effectrequest/{name}/{imagename:[a-zA-Z0-9%\\.]*}", 
        headers="Accept=*/*", method=RequestMethod.GET, 
        produces = "application/json")
public @ResponseBody EffectRequest effectRequest(
        @PathVariable("name") String name,
        @PathVariable("imagename") String imageName)
{
    return new EffectRequest(2, "result");
}
```

Which returns JSON content using MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter. I make a test jQuery AJAX call to this mapping with ...

```
var effectName = 'Blur';
var imageName = 'Blah.jpg';
var requestUri = '/effectrequest/' + effectName + '/' + imageName;
alert(requestUri);

$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajax({
        url: /*[+   [[${hostname}]] + requestUri   +]*/
    }).then(function(data) {
       $('.effect').append(data.id);
       $('.image').append(data.content);
    });
});
```

This generates a URI of http://localhost/effectrequest/Blur/Blah.jpg and in a debugging session the filename is received correctly in the effectRequest() method above.  However, the client or jQuery AJAX call receives a HTTP 406 error (Not Acceptable) from the server even with the `produces = "application/json"` in the RequestMapping.

After much debugging later, I have this narrowed down - when I modify the test  javascript code to generate a URI of `http://localhost/effectrequest/Blur/Blah.json` it works.  So either Tomcat or `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` is causing the HTTP 406 error by looking at the filename extension at the end of the URI and deciding that the JSON content I'm sending back is not a good match.

Is there anyway to override this behaviour without having to encode the . (dot) in the filename?

Comment: Also, I have tried a forced URIEncode on the filename by replacing the . (dot) with %2E.  The RequestMapping does decode the filename correctly but I still get the HTTP 406 error when the JSON gets sent.  So, I may be forced to encode the . (dot) some other way if there isn't a way to change the default configuration in this Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, Spring MVC prefers to use the request's path when it's trying to figure out the media type for a response to a request. This is described in the [javadoc for `ContentNegotiationConfigurer.favorPathExtension()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/config/annotation/ContentNegotiationConfigurer.html#favorPathExtension-boolean-):

> Indicate whether the extension of the request path should be used to determine the requested media type with the highest priority.
>
> By default this value is set to true in which case a request for `/hotels.pdf` will be interpreted as a request for `"application/pdf"` regardless of the Accept header.

In your case this means that the request for `/effectrequest/Blur/Blah.jpg` is being interpreted as a request for `image/jpeg` which leaves `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConveter` trying to write an `image/jpeg` response which it is unable to do.

You can easily change this configuration using `ContentNegotiationConfigurer` accessed by extending `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter`. For example:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(
            ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(false);
    }
}
```